# UnitTest framework for JNI calls?

Tags: android, unit-testing, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm building our own unit test framework. My project is migrated from legacy code, Android just provides UI implementation, so there's lots of jni calls. I'd like to be focused on testing jni calls, since it's painful and hard to debug native code in Eclipse/ADT, you know.

To reduce complexity, I'm planning to write extra mock java classes, that means I won't really test my java implementation, to test all jni calls, and all tests could run in command line, without launching an emulator at all, finally get a result report definitely.

I've read Android Testing Fundamentals, I don't think it's quite convenient. BTW, I used google c++ testing framework to test my legacy code in the past. Is gtest another option? Is there any other solution?